# how to update insert dynamic filed in SOLR

Tags: curl, solr

I have a collection where schema.xml mentioned dynamic field as

```
<dynamicField name="dynm_*"  type="string" indexed="true"  stored="false"  multiValued="true"omitNorms="true"/>
```

I would like to insert a new document with a field name called "dynm_field" using CURL request.

Can I do it and how??

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link for examples:

[curl + solr + jason](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON)

Plenty of examples including multivalued fields. Try that:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"dynm_field": [ "aaa", "bbb" ]}]'
```